# SharePoint 2010 Site for Employees (intranet) and Teams within Department

Tags: intranet

I am developing an intranet for my financial institution which is based on different departments and the visitors (Employees of organization) visits the department site and browse the documents from different libraries and access forms (pdf format) ...

But I want my company to take advantage of sharepoint and use it for internal use also like in HR there are 3 teams working for example . Loans, Leaves, Insurance etc. And I want to create a sub site which has Loan, Leaves and Insurance and they maintain their documents there as central place instead of float multiple copies through emails and maintain in their hard drives this way I would save network storage media space and they would get benefit of version controlling and central repository with security.

my question is when visitor hits the HR page they see document libraries which is available publicly...but don't know if I should place a Link for HR's internal team sites on hr page or give the link privately to each team which they would place on browser and get in their.

How should I brand the portal

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking at security rather than just branding. Depending upon the requirement you can look at the following:

1. Each department gets it's own sub-sites. With this approach all users who have access to the Root site will be able to see data from the sub-sites as the sub sites inherit the permissions. So to make the data visible only for the department employees, the permission inheritance has to be broken at one of the following levels - site , library, folder or document. For ease of User management, use permission inheritance wherever possible. Advantage with using sub sites is that we can use the SharePoint Out-of-the-Box components (navigation, web parts etc.).
2. Each department gets it's own Site collection. With this approach all employees of the department get read/write access while users from other departments can be provided with just read access. With this approach you might need to create custom navigation for users to navigate across different departmental sites.

Please read the following article on how to plan site permissions -
[Plan site permissions in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262778.aspx)

Let me know if u need any more details.

Comment: My portal is intranet portal and the target audience is of two types. 1. Employees who will visit departmental sites and can see/get documents from the document libraries..this is one case and its working perfectly through the top navigation bar. 

Second case, Each departments will have individual team sites for their internal working like Loans team, Leaves team and Insurance Team...every team will have their own document libaries..security i can implement not an issue...all I want to know is what is the best practice to show the navigation link for private team sites

Comment: Additionally..should I just create a team site under HR and give the link to the teams and not display that link anywhere on HR's page for employees. http://mycompany/HR/HRTeamsSite/ and HRTeamSites will have customize access permissions.

Comment: How many teams site would have under each department?

Comment: well I can do is also to create one sub site and create pages for loans, leaves and insurance and set permissions on their list/libraries Or can create 4 individual team sites max.

Comment: two approaches - use the Navigation which fine as long as there aren't too many team sites (at peer level or as a sub sites). Another approach is put this team site links in the list with item level permissions. Then provide a view wherein u can only those sites on which have access. This list view webpart can be on the home page of the department site. To make it visible to only the department employees, u set target audience to the list view web part.

Comment: please refrain for using the comments as a discussion board! If you want to discuss further regarding Q/A please use our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/sharepoint)